# How to add elements of a struct into a function

Tags: swift, struct

I'm a real newbie at this so I apologize for how simple this question might be.

I'm trying to mess around with structs and basically wanting to grab the variables of my struct and create a simple calculation.

```
struct Sword {
let name: String
let damage, weight, handle, enchantment : Int
}

let swordSwing = damage + weight + handle + enchantment
```

I get an error "Use of unresolved identifier". What am I doing wrong here ?

I tried to add that line of code in my struct and had an error to use self. but when trying that i get another error.

I keep seeing initialization of elements of a struct and I'm wondering if that's what I need to do but I just need a little nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

At least you have to initialize an instance of the struct and assign values. Then you have to reference the instance when accessing its properties

```
struct Sword {
    let name: String
    let damage, weight, handle, enchantment : Int
}

let sword = Sword(name: "Foo", damage: 2, weight: 4, handle: 6, enchantment: 8)
let swordSwing = sword.damage + sword.weight + sword.handle + sword.enchantment
```

Or you put the math into the struct

```
struct Sword {
    let name: String
    let damage, weight, handle, enchantment : Int

    var swing : Int {
        return damage + weight + handle + enchantment
    }
}

let sword = Sword(name: "Foo", damage: 2, weight: 4, handle: 6, enchantment: 8)

let swordSwing = sword.swing
```

Please read [Swift Language Guide: Classes and Structs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82)

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. So basically I have to create that variable within the struct and let Xcode know that this Int will be the product of damage + weight + handle + enchantment. Thank you very much vadian !

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create a new instance of `Sword`

```
let sword = Sword(name: "name", damage: 0, weight: 1, handle: 2, enchantment: 3)
```

Then later use the dot notation to access the variables stored inside the structure

```
let swordSwing = sword.damage + sword.weight + sword.handle + sword.enchantment
```